# php not running script

Tags: php, email, pligg

i want to send mails using php. for that i have to take mails id from database so i am fetching data from tables and then i am using mail functions  but when i am going server and run it then it shows nothing blank page appears site is pligg cms base site

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sending HTML email using PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $mysql_host = "localhost";
    $mysql_database = "db";
    $mysql_user = "r";
    $mysql_password = "s#1#";
    $con=mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
    if(!$con)
    {
          echo "can't connect";
         die("failed connect".mysql_error());

    }
     $db_select=mysql_select_db($mysql_database);
    if(!$db_select)
    {
        echo "db not connected";
    die(" failed user".mysql_error());
   }

   $query1 = "SELECT * FROM  pligg_users"
   $subject = "Exclusive Facebook Cover Offer.";
   $message = "hello";
   $message .= "  <a href='www.getlikeseasy.com'>Read more</a>";
   $message = wordwrap($message,70);
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
   $results = mysql_query($query1);
   if(!$results) 
    {
    echo "query";
    die(mysql_error());
     }
    while($result_array = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
     {    
    $c = $result_array['user_email'];
    $retval = mail($c,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if( $retval == true )
    {
        echo .$i." Message sent successfully... to".$c;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo .$i." Message could not be sent... to".$c;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    $i++;
}
   echo "email sent";
 ?>
<?php
  mysql_close($con);
 ?> 
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions, **they are deprecated** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: So what does the error log files of your systems http server say? That is where php errors usually are written to.

Comment: @D4V1D that is not the issue here. You should at least mark such comments as "side notes".

Comment: Are you sure the query gives correct result ?

Comment: @arkascha That is why I've posted this as a comment and not an answer to his specific problem.

Comment: yes query is right @ darshan jain

Comment: *Blank screen, a.k.a. "White screen of death!"*: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Good for many things, such as *parse errors* and DB errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blank pages are often the result of syntax errors. I would recommend enabling error reporting so you can be self-sufficient with debugging.
I have not worked with PHP for many years now, but I expect this SO post will help: [PHP: I get a completely blank page, I don't know how to debug this in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247823/php-i-get-a-completely-blank-page-i-dont-know-how-to-debug-this-in-php)

You're missing a semi-colon here:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM  pligg_users"
```

I don't know if that will fix all of it but it will definitely help.

Edit:

On the code below you have placed a '.' before echoing a variable on lines 3 and 8, remove those as well.

```
if( $retval == true )
{
    echo .$i." Message sent successfully... to".$c;
    echo "<br>";
}
else
{
    echo .$i." Message could not be sent... to".$c;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: after seeing your post i have correct my mistakes but then also it shows blank page

Comment: I have edited my post after discovering two more errors.