# Roundcube blank screen

Tags: php, lamp, roundcube

I'm about to set up a private webserver with apache 2.4.10, Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.20-MariaDB and php 5.6.13. I wanted to get roundcube runnig, which I used on my old debian 6 server without any issues.
For three days now I'm trying just make the login screen apear, but all I get is a blank page. If I put a simple  index page into the roundcube documentroot folder it is shown. In my opinion all reguirements from http://trac.roundcube.net/wiki/Howto_Requirements are met.
I don't get any useful log-output, apache reports no errors, roundcube log is empty, although I enabled debugging.
I also added

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

to the top of the index page (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247823/php-i-get-a-completely-blank-page-i-dont-know-how-to-debug-this-in-php#_=_))
There are some posts mentioning the "white screen of death" in the www, but the hints didn't help, e. g.: changing rights on log and temp folder, or disabling certain modules.
The problem is, that I simply don't know where to look next.
Could anybody help me? What can I do next to isolate the problem?

Thanks,
Martin